# How to do generic copy constructor in java

Tags: java

could you please advise or give some hints how to do following.
I have POJO lets say it is called BankHistoryData. I would like to copy data from two tables into this POJO (main table - Bank and its archive - BankArchive). Tables have a lot of fields which are basiclly the same, so I would not like to repeat my self.
I googled around and found a tool that could help me with this - Java generic constructor.
But, I am a little bit new with generics and not sure how exactly to do it.
I suppose I should have something like this:

```
public class BankHistoryData<T extends Serializable> {
    // I would like to set this fields from the object T
    private field1;
    private field2;
    // and many more ...

    T a; // source object from which to copy values
    public BankHistoryData(T a) { 
       this.a = a; 
       copyData();
    } 

    // NOT SURE ABOUT THIS ... something like this
    public void copyData() {
      if(T instanceof Bank) { 
        this.field1 = ((Bank)a).getSomeField();
        // and so on ...
      } else if (T instanceof BankArchive) {
         this.field1 = ((BankArchive)a).getSomeField();
         // and so on ...
      } else {
         trow new IllegalArgumentException("Not supported table");
      }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

mismas

[EDIT]
I have decided not to use generic for this, as I think those 2 cents from @Alex where for that. Instead I will do this copy logic in my business logic service layer (POJO will remain "stupid").
Although, I will make those two hibernate objects to implement common interface (only getter methods of shared fields will be here). And finally, I will make a copy method on my business logic service layer and make it to take that interface parameter for copying fields.
Hope this will help someone. Also, any comments are welcome.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just create a super interface e.g. `IBankData` and have your `Bank` and `BankArchive` both implementing that interface and pass in the interface?

If you really have some specific logic as per Bank/BankArchive, you can do

```
public class MyClass<T extends IBankData> {

    public void copyData(T instance) {
        T.getFieldXXX() // this would work because T extends IBankData

        if (T instanceof Bank) {
            ((Bank) T).getBankSpecificField();
        }
    }
}
```

BTW - just my 2 cents - in a well designed structure, you normally don't have to do `instanceof` unless at the logical facade / dispatching class.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. However, I'm not sure if Bank and BankArchive are modifiable.

Comment: I didn't mention that Bank and BankArchive are Hibernate objects. So, I am not sure what to put in this interface you are suggesting to do? (getters and setters?) P.s I can modify them to certain extent ...

Comment: @mismas Yes, any common getters and setters which are shared between 'Bank' and 'BankArchive'.

Comment: :) I have decided not to use generic for this, as I think those 2 cents where for that :P Instead I will do this copy logic in my business logic service layer (POJO will remain "stupid"). Although, I will make those two hibernate objects to implement common interface (only getter methods of shared fields will be here). And finally, I will make a copy method on my business logic service layer and make it to take that interface parameter for copying fields. Hope this will help someone. Also, any comments are welcome. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

T can't guarantee, as it is written, that the required fields exist.

I would change it to :

```
public class BankHistoryData<T extends MySpecificInterfaceOrSuperClass> {}
```